# Getting errors when execute test in Rails for activerecord object relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, capybara, minitest

I have a view partial _patients.html.erb where I want to show a nested attribute from Consultation model, so I am accessing to ActiveRecord relationship object this way:

### my models

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :medic
  has_many :consultations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :consultations
end

class Consultation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

### on my dashboard_controller.rb

```
..some code..

protected
    def reason_for_consultation(patient)
        patient = patient
        @reason = Consultation.where(patient_id: patient.id).order(created_at: :desc).limit(1)
        #=> @reason: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Consultation id: 371, reason_for_consultation: "Sunt impedit adipisci molestiae doloremque sed.">]>
        @reason_for_consultation = @reason[0].reason_for_consultation
    end

    helper_method :reason_for_consultation
```

### the view partial _patients.html.erb

```
<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
    .. code ..
    <p>Reason for consultation: <%= reason_for_consultation(patient) %></p>
    .. code ..
<% end %>
```

Note: the code is working fine, is showing data for each patient in the view, the problem is when I run tests (minitest) I'm getting several warnings and errors like this:

- DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (more descriptions of the error followed by):

  - Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible link, or
  - Expected false to be truthy, or
  - Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <500: Internal Server Error>

But if I comment in my partial: `<%# reason_for_consultation(patient) %>`, and run tests again all are pass.

All errors are related to dashboard interaction

Any idea what is happening and how to solve it?

### Edit:

Versions:
 - rails: 5.0.0.1
 - minitest: 5.9.1
 - ruby 2.3.3p222

rails test trace:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from block in <class:DashboardFlowTest> at my_app/test/integration/dashboard_flow_test.rb:19)
DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from block in <class:DashboardFlowTest> at my_app/test/integration/dashboard_flow_test.rb:19)
 FAIL["test_should_be_in_dashboard", DashboardFlowTest, 0.46483432999957586]
 test_should_be_in_dashboard#DashboardFlowTest (0.46s)
        Expected false to be truthy.
        test/integration/dashboard_flow_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:DashboardFlowTest>'

DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from block in <class:DashboardFlowTest> at my_app/test/integration/dashboard_flow_test.rb:24)
DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from block in <class:DashboardFlowTest> at my_app/test/integration/dashboard_flow_test.rb:24)
ERROR["test_should_be_show_new_patient_form", DashboardFlowTest, 0.5577200539992191]
 test_should_be_show_new_patient_form#DashboardFlowTest (0.56s)
Capybara::ElementNotFound:         Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible link "Create Patient"
            test/integration/dashboard_flow_test.rb:25:in `block in <class:DashboardFlowTest>'

DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from block in <class:DashboardFlowTest> at my_app/test/integration/dashboard_flow_test.rb:30)
DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from block in <class:DashboardFlowTest> at my_app/test/integration/dashboard_flow_test.rb:30)
ERROR["test_should_be_show_patient_list_page", DashboardFlowTest, 0.6530102200049441]
 test_should_be_show_patient_list_page#DashboardFlowTest (0.65s)
Capybara::ElementNotFound:         Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible link "Patient List"
            test/integration/dashboard_flow_test.rb:31:in `block in <class:DashboardFlowTest>'

DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from block in <class:PaymentMethodsFlowTest> at my_app/test/integration/payment_methods_flow_test.rb:19)
DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from block in <class:PaymentMethodsFlowTest> at my_app/test/integration/payment_methods_flow_test.rb:19)
ERROR["test_0001_log into dashboard as premium user", PaymentMethodsFlowTest, 4.802539983000315]
 test_0001_log into dashboard as premium user#PaymentMethodsFlowTest (4.80s)
Capybara::ElementNotFound:         Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible link "Show Payment Methods"
            test/integration/payment_methods_flow_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:PaymentMethodsFlowTest>'

DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from block (2 levels) in <class:ConsultNewPatientFlowTest> at my_app/test/integration/consult_new_patient_flow_test.rb:37)
DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from block (2 levels) in <class:ConsultNewPatientFlowTest> at my_app/test/integration/consult_new_patient_flow_test.rb:37)
ERROR["test_0001_end to end consult a patient", #<Class:0x0055b32a91d1a0>, 4.885057498999231]
 test_0001_end to end consult a patient#Medic can consult a new patient Feature Test (4.89s)
Capybara::ElementNotFound:         Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible link "Create Patient"
            test/integration/consult_new_patient_flow_test.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ConsultNewPatientFlowTest>'

DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from block (2 levels) in <class:PremiumLoginFlowTest> at my_app/test/integration/premium_login_flow_test.rb:20)
DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from block (2 levels) in <class:PremiumLoginFlowTest> at my_app/test/integration/premium_login_flow_test.rb:20)
 FAIL["test_0001_login premium", #<Class:0x0055b32a8e22f8>, 5.003259566998167]
 test_0001_login premium#Medic with account and payment method Feature Test (5.00s)
        Expected false to be truthy.
        test/integration/premium_login_flow_test.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <class:PremiumLoginFlowTest>'

DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from block in <class:DashboardControllerTest> at my_app/test/controllers/dashboard_controller_test.rb:21)
DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from block in <class:DashboardControllerTest> at my_app/test/controllers/dashboard_controller_test.rb:21)
 FAIL["test_should_get_dashboard", DashboardControllerTest, 5.078975292002724]
 test_should_get_dashboard#DashboardControllerTest (5.08s)
        Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <500: Internal Server Error>
        test/controllers/dashboard_controller_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:DashboardControllerTest>'

  63/63: [==================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:05, Time: 00:00:05

Finished in 5.30410s
63 tests, 147 assertions, 3 failures, 4 errors, 0 skips
```

### Edit 2:

Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <500: Internal Server Error>
my_app/test/controllers/dashboard_controller_test.rb:21

```
require 'test_helper'

class DashboardControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # Needed for authenticate user
  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  setup do
    # Login medic for before_filter authenticate_user!
    @medic = medics(:medic_one)
    @medic.confirmed_at = Time.now
    @medic.save
    login_as(@medic, :scope => :medic)
    # Set payment for medic
    @medic.payment_methods.reload
  end

  test "should get dashboard" do
    get dashboard_index_url
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you include the stacktrace?

Comment: And edit your post and add what versions of Rails, Minitest, and Ruby you use

Comment: sure @JoshBrody

Comment: Versions: - rails: 5.0.0.1 - minitest: 5.9.1 - ruby 2.3.3p222, @Phlip

Comment: Why are the tests running Capybara? A simple "functional" test can cover your code...

Comment: @Phlip Is capybara causing this error for some reason?

Comment: Edit your post and add a sample of your tests.

Comment: @Philip I have added a sample test, you need some test specially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller test failure shows you what your issue, the page is returning a 500 error status rather than a 2XX status - which tells you there is an error rendering the page.  This would also be why Capybara isn't finding any of the expected elements on the page (because the page isn't actually being rendered).  If you look in your `test.log` it should tell you exactly where in your templates the error is coming but since commenting out the `<%# reason_for_consultation(patient) %` fixes the page we can pretty safely assume that's where the error is.

Looking at the code for `reason_for_consultation` we can see that if a patient hasn't already had a consultation then `@reason[0]` would be `nil` and `@reason[0].reason_for_consultation` would raise an error for trying to call `reason_for_consultation` on `nil`.  One possible way to fix that would be to use the safe navigation operator and change the line to

```
@reason[0]&.reason_for_consultation
```

Note: In the future the whole implementation of that routine/partial should probably be refactored to remove the N + 1 query you have going on there.

As for the `DEPRECATION WARNING` lines about `original_exception` - it's impossible to say where that is actually coming from without a deeper stacktrace, but try looking at `my_app/test/controllers/dashboard_controller_test.rb` line 21 and see what is being called there.  It could just be that you need to update some of your testing gems.

Comment: `@reason[0]&.reason_for_consultation` works great, thanks for the explanation, now test are passing, I will follow your recommendations about the log, and the refactoring in the future. thank you very much.